# Python class vs Dict for client list

Tags: python, class, dictionary, flask

So right now I am trying to understand the difference between when to use a Class and when to use a Dictionary for holding data.

The specific problem I am trying to work this out for, is for managing sessions in a flask application.  As of right I have two dictionaries.  I don't need to debug anything specifically so the code provided will be snippets with a few comments.

```
client = {}
client[session['user_id'] = request.sid #stores the active socket ID

online_users = {}
online_users[session['user_id'] = {}
online_user[session['user_id']['somestr'] = somevariable/string
online_user[session['user_id']['somestr1'] = somevariable/string 
online_user[session['user_id']['somestr2'] = {}
#etc
```

The only real logic that I am doing in these dictionaries, is updating the values as users navigate the website.  So if I moved these into classes, really I would only have getters and setters.  Also some of these key value pairs might not even exist, so the would constantly be getting added and removed over time.

There are a few parts to this question.

1) Should I consider moving something like this into a class.  It does have logic, but it seems like with enough clients logged in at once, using a dictionary might have a real performance benefit.

2) If I were to want to change these to classes, how exactly would that work?

```
Class Online_Users():

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.user = session['user_id']
    self.somevar = 'somestring'
    #etc
```

Then when it comes time to create an instance of the class

```
clients = {}
clients[session['user_id']] = Online_Users(arguments)
```

I don't really see a way to do this without having some kind of a dictionary storing the session values.

EDIT: So a 3rd question might also be helpful.
If I were to want to do this entirely using classes, how am I connecting a class instance to each individual user?  I'm having a difficult time understanding how this works without a dictionary.  It may be related to my poor understanding of how sessions work.

Comment: Don't use getters and setters in Python.

Comment: Fair point, properties is more what I meant, getters and setters just seems like an easy descriptive way of explaining that.

Comment: Will you even need properties? Anyway, there can be some real memory efficiency gains using classes with `__slots__` as compared to a `dict`. I would even say you might be able to get away with `namedtuple`, but since you need to update values, the immutability might be a thorn in your side.

Comment: https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0